# How to remove the for loop and perform vectorization for data frame variables?

Tags: r, for-loop, vectorization

I have a data frame (V6Stationary42Obs1D.df) with 6 variables. For the 1st variable of my data frame I obtain the value as follows ("1" in effrectpl[i,1] indicates I obtained the value for the 1st variable):

```
sum <- 0
for (i in as.integer(1:5)) { # 5= no. of variables - 1 = 6-1=5
sum <- sum + conditionalGb(as.matrix(V6Stationary42Obs1D.df[gctemplate(6,1,1)[effrectpl[i,1],]][(1+0):42,]), nx = 1, ny = 1, order = 5)[[2]]
}
sum
```

For the 2nd variable of my data frame I obtain the value as follows ("2" in effrectpl[i,2] indicates I obtained the value for the 2nd variable):

```
sum <- 0
for (i in as.integer(1:5)) {
sum <- sum + conditionalGb(as.matrix(V6Stationary42Obs1D.df[gctemplate(6,1,1)[effrectpl[i,2],]][(1+0):42,]), nx = 1, ny = 1, order = 5)[[2]]
} # "6" in gctemplate(6,1,1) is the no. of variables in the data frame
# there is no change other than the one in effrectpl[i,2] for the 2nd variable
sum
```

There are 6 variables in my data variable, and I have to do the same for each variable (The number of variables will change when I convert this mass to a function; notably, for neuroscience sometimes there may be about 300 variables! and guess the calculation load). I need a vectorized solution that will overcome the above trouble.

**What I did (thought):**

```
sum <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0)  
for (i in as.integer(1:5)) {
sum??? <- sum + ????
}
sum
```

Though I know s/t/...apply family, in this particular problem I could not figure out how to handle them as well.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thx in advance.

Note: I found the following for-inside-for solution, and now, think that maybe a vectorized solution either difficult or unnecessary in the above case. Anyway, if I see some sort of non-for solution, I will be glad.

```
for (j in as.integer(1:6)) {
  sum[j] <- 0
  for (i in as.integer(1:5)) {
    sum[j] <- sum[j] + conditionalGb(as.matrix(V6Stationary42Obs1D.df[gctemplate(6,1,1)[effrectpl[i,j],]][(1+0):42,]), nx = 1, ny = 1, order = 5)[[2]]
  }
  print(sum[j])
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If computation speed is not your concern and you understand what you are doing then for loop is fine. Its not wrong. It can be made more efficient by vectorization but thats not a necessity.

It is very difficult to provide you with a solution as the example is very hard to follow and calls functions which I have no idea whats its doing, but in general if you have a function f(i) that depends on i you can turn

```
sum = 0
for( i in 1:n) sum = sum + f(i)
```

into

```
sum(sapply(1:n,function(i) f(i)))
```

BTW its a bad idea to call your variable sum since that is also the name of a common function in R.

Comment: Thank you Rohit. I tested your code with the function multipleby2 <- function(i){2*i} and they both gave the same answer: R> sum = 0  > for( i in 1:5) sum = sum + multipleby2(i) R> sum R> [1] 30. On other side: R> sum(sapply(1:5,function(i) multipleby2(i))) R> [1] 30. I can now change the code accordingly. Anyway, this questions in fact hint that sometimes for-inside-for may prevent the need for the usage of advanced techniques.